# Error in query, two select statements with left join?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two select statements:

```
A: select a.1,a.2,a.3 from table1 a

B: select b.1,b.2,b.3 from table1 b
```

Now I join these two statements?

I tried in the below way and got error:

```
select * 
(select a.1,a.2,a.3 from table1 a) aa
left join 
(select b.1,b.2,b.3 from table1 b) bb
aa.a.1 = bb.b.1;
```

Comment: You are missing where before aa.a.1 = bb.b.1,

Comment: Please provide schema for both tables, as well as what you're trying to get from both. This seems quite unclear with all these A's and B's

Comment: What error do you get? (And why do you let us guess at all instead of just telling us right away?)

Answer (score 0):

Within your Left Join, you need to include the `ON/WHERE` clause:

```
select * 
(select a.1,a.2,a.3 from table1 a) aa
left join 
(select b.1,b.2,b.3 from table1 b) bb
aa.a.1 = bb.b.1,
```

should be in the format:

```
   SELECT *
   (SELECT a.1, a.2, a.3 FROM table1 a) aa
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT b.1,b.2,b.3 FROM table2 b) bb
   ON a.1 = b.1
   WHERE ...
```

For more clarification, please see this image:

[image]

As it currently stands, it's quite hard to distinguish what exactly your requirements are in terms of what you want the query to return, but I op this image will **visually** display the syntax for each of the joins.

Comment: aa.a.1 = bb.b.1  <= is it correct to call like this

Comment: but left join in two select statment what is the best format of that

Comment: WHERE ... <----should be what?

Comment: select * 
(select a.key,a.2,a.3 from table1 a) aa
left join 
(select b.key,b.2,b.3 from table1 b) bb
on a.key = b.key  where (<----what should put in?)

Comment: top right or middle right option (both are right joins) but the `WHERE` clause could be a.1 = b.1 (this would give top right option)

Comment: Thanks, but then what is the difference on "ON  a.1 = b.1" AND ""where  a.1 = b.1

Comment: please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722795/in-sql-mysql-what-is-the-difference-between-on-and-where-in-a-join-statem) to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers (a.1, a.2, i.e. columns 1 and 2 for table alias a) are usually not valid column names. Are the columns really named thus? Then you'd need something to indicate that these are column names. Depending on the dbms that could be `a.1` or "a.1" or [a.1]. Or use different names, such as num1, num2, num3, or one, two, three, etc.

EDIT: You are also missing the word `ON` before your criteria. And `aa.a.1` is invalid, for your table alias is now aa and the column name is still "1" and the table alias a is no longer known. So it must be `a."1"` instead. Moreover you are missing the keyword FROM for your first derived table.

```
select * 
from      (select a."1", a."2", a."3" from table1 a) aa
left join (select b."1", b."2", b."3" from table1 b) bb ON aa."1" = bb."1";
```