# MySQL placement of conditions in on-clauses of multiple outer joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, on-clause

As a follow up to [In SQL / MySQL, what is the difference between "ON" and "WHERE" in a join statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722795/in-sql-mysql-what-is-the-difference-between-on-and-where-in-a-join-statem) and [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause) - it **does** matter if a condition is placed in the on-clause vs. the where-clause in an outer join.

However, does it matter *which* on-clause the condition is placed in when there are multiple outer joins?

For example, could these produce different results?

```
select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.fid=t2.id and t2.col=val
                 left join t3 on t2.fid=t3.id;
```

vs:

```
select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.fid=t2.id
                 left join t3 on t2.fid=t3.id and t2.col=val;
```

Comment: `val`:  what is that?  `t1.val` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely they are different.

The fisrt query will only have `t2` rows that satisfy `t2.col=val`

The second query will include all `t2` rows and only list `t3` when `t2.col=val`

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Jasen.
The way I'm thinking of it is that if you want to filter the left-most table (and on) - use "where", the next table - use the left-most "on", then the next "on", etc.  So the order of filtering is: where, on #1, on #2 ...

Comment: yes, usually `where` only mentions the starting table, if you use columns from other tables in `where` it often implies a `is not null` on the column from that table turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.

Answer (score 1):

The queries are not equivalent. It is easy to construct a counter example:

```
create table t1 (id int not null, val int not null);
create table t2 (id int not null, val int not null);
create table t3 (id int not null, val int not null);
insert into t1 (id, val) values (1,1);
insert into t2 (id, val) values (1,1);
insert into t3 (id, val) values (1,1);

select * from t1 
left join t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id 
    and t2.val = 2 
left join t3 
    on t2.id = t3.id;
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+
| id | val | id   | val  | id   | val  |
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |   1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+

select * from t1 
left join t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id 
left join t3 
    on t2.id = t3.id 
    and t2.val = 2;
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+
| id | val | id   | val  | id   | val  |
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |   1 |    1 |    1 | NULL | NULL |
+----+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the queries:

```
select *
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.fid = t2.id left join
     t3
     on t2.fid = t3.id and t2.col = val;
```

Yes, the results are different.  If you were using `inner join` they would be the same, but the `left join` changes things -- because the `join` clause does not do any filtering of rows.

I think the simplest explanation is that the join between `t1` and `t2` will include all rows from `t1` as well as all matching rows from `t2` -- even those where `t2.col <> val`.  These remain in the result set, because the next `left join` does not filter them out.

In fact, the condition `t2.col = val` in the second `on` clause does not affect which rows are in the result set.  If there is a match, then the row from `t3` stays based on the first condition.  If there is no match, then the row from `t3` is still in the result set -- but the `t3` columns will be `NULL`.

In this version:

```
select *
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.fid = t2.id  and t2.col = val left join
     t3
     on t2.fid = t3.id;
```

The first join gets all rows from `t1` and only matching rows from `t2` where `t2.col = val`.  The third join can then add more rows.

Note:  there are definitely situations where the two queries would return the same results.  But, the following data would generate different results (assume val = 0):

t1

```
fid
1
```

t2

```
fid   col
1     0
1     1
```

t3

```
id 
1
```

The query with the condition in the second `on` clause will return:

```
1    1    0    1
1    1    1    NULL
```

The query with the condition in the first `on` clause will return:

```
1    1    0    1
```