# Using Where and on keywords for checking conditions in Select statements

Tags: mysql, database

Whats the difference between using **On** and **Where**  keywords in a Sql query to check conditions.

```
select * from child_table inner join parent_table p on p.id>0;

select * from child_table inner join parent_table p where p.id>0;
```

Both these queries are providing me the same result

Comment: They are equivalent statements, but the first is correct SQL.  The second only works in MySQL and looks like a bastardization of the language.  `INNER JOIN` should always have an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` is a part of the `SELECT` query as a whole. And `ON` is a individual join.

See this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722795/in-sql-mysql-what-is-the-difference-between-on-and-where-in-a-join-statem).