# Join two table and get all the employee name with attendance

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables
First is Employee and Second is Attendance

**Employee Table** :-

[image]

**Attendance Table** :-

[image]

there is only 3 Employee's attendance entered in Attendance Table on AttDate = '2017-09-05'.

i use this query to join these table :-

```
select EmpName,Attendance from Employee Left join Attendance on Employee.EmpId = Attendance.refId where AttDate ='2017-09-05'
```

and it's show this output :-

[image]

but i need this output ( employees whose attendance did not enter in Attendance Table will also Show with Null attendance ) :-

[image]

what should i change in the query to get this output ?

Comment: @nada left and left outer are the same thing

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join on the date value as well, the result set will not be eliminated:

```
select EmpName,Attendance 
from Employee Left join Attendance on Employee.EmpId = Attendance.refId and AttDate ='2017-09-05'
```

You will also get the employees that have not attended on that day.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722795/in-sql-mysql-what-is-the-difference-between-on-and-where-in-a-join-statem) for more info on the difference between having a condition on the `where` clause vs having it on the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are restricting it with a `WHERE` so the two EmpID's who didn't do the course on that day wont show up.

You can change your `where` to:

`WHERE AttDate = '2017-09-05' or AttDate is null;`

but that will bring back all results who have a null in the date