# Trying to simplify code to get results from 2 tables excluding some from table 1 and some from table 2

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

**Updated as pr. @philipxy suggestions in comments below**
(thanks for the input)

I have 2 tables in a MySQL database with the following structure

**forumtopic**

```
| id |  date  | dateEdit | userID |  title  |  summary  |  randomString  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | <date> |  <date>  |   1    | Welcome |  Welcome  |  jhdsa76dfasi  |
|    |        |          |        |         |  message  |                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | <date> |  <date>  |   5    | LEFT    | How to    |  oiasud88ashk  |
|    |        |          |        | JOIN    | LEFT JOIN |                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | <date> |  <date>  |   6    | Not the | How to do |  lkdsajlkjdf7  |
|    |        |          |        | right   | it right  |                |
|    |        |          |        | way     |           |                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| n  | <date> |  <date>  | <user> | title-n | summary-n | randomString-n |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(user with id 1 wrote topic with id 1)
(user with id 5 wrote topic with id 2)
(user with id 6 wrote topic with id 3)
etc.

**forumtopicview**

```
-----------------------------
| id |  userID  |  topicID  |
-----------------------------
| 1  |    1     |     2     |
-----------------------------
| 2  |    5     |     1     |
-----------------------------
| 3  |    5     |     3     |
-----------------------------
| 4  |    6     |     1     |
-----------------------------
.
.
.
-----------------------------
| n  | <userID> | <topicID> |
-----------------------------
```

(user with id 1 watched topic with id 2 from the above table)
(user with id 5 watched topic with id 1 from the above table)
(user with id 5 watched topic with id 3 from the above table)
(user with id 6 watched topic with id 1 from the above table)
etc.

**What I'm trying to do**
I'm trying to get info on all topics that isn't written by the user logged in and haven't been viewed by the user logged in already

So for user 1:
User 1 wrote topic 1 and viewed topic 2
SELECT statement should then show info on all topics that are not 1 and 2 (ie. 3)

For user 5:
User 5 wrote topic 2 and viewed topic 1 and 3
SELECT statement should then show info on all topics that are not 1, 2, and 3 (ie. no results)

For user 6:
User 6 wrote topic 3 and viewed topic 1
SELECT statement should then show info on all topics that are not 1 and 3 (ie. 2)

How do I do that in a single SELECT statement?

**connection.php**

```
try {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "******";
    $password = "**************";
    $database = "*****";
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;charset=$charset";

    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    $pdo = new PDO ( $dsn , $username , $password , $opt );

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

    file_put_contents ( 'PDOError.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );
    echo "Failed to connect to database!";
    die ();

}
```

Code that works but is way to cumbersome:

functions.php

```
require ( '../scripts/connection.php' );

function getTopic ($pdo) {

    // Set userID for user logged in
    if ( isset ( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {

        $userID = $_SESSION['id'];

    }

    try {

        // Find all topics not written by user logged in
        $prepareTopic = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT id , date , title , summary , randomString FROM forumtopic WHERE userID != ? ORDER BY date DESC" );
        $prepareTopic->execute([$userID]);
        $getTopic = $prepareTopic->fetchAll();

    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {

        file_put_contents ( 'error.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );

    }

    // If found topics not written by user logged in
    if ( $getTopic ) {

        foreach ( $getTopic as $row ) {

            // Set topicID and use it to see if user logged in has already viewed it
            $topicID = $row['id'];

            try {

                // Find if specific topic viewed by user logged in
                $prepareTopicview = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT id FROM forumtopicview WHERE ( userID = ? AND topicID = ? ) LIMIT 1" );
                $prepareTopicview->execute([$userID,$topicID]);
                $getTopicView = $prepareTopicview->fetch();

            } catch ( PDOException $e ) {

                file_put_contents ( 'error.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );

            }

            // Only if specific topic not viewed by user logged in
            if ( !$getTopicView ) {

                // Set needed variables
                $dateTopic[] = $row['date'];
                $titleTopic[] = $row['title'];
                $summaryTopic[] = $row['summary'];
                $randomStringTopic[] = $row['randomString'];

            }

        }

    }

}
```

But this is way to much code for this

**What I want to do**

functions.php

```
if ( isset ( $_SESSION['id']; ) ) {

    $userID = $_SESSION['id'];

}

try {

    $prepareTopic = $pdo->( "SELECT..." );
    $prepareTopic->execute([$userID]);
    $getTopic = $prepareTopic->fetchAll();

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

    file_put_contents ( 'error.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );

}

if ( $getTopic ) {

    foreach ( $getTopic as $row ) {

        $dateTopic[] = $row['date'];
        $titleTopic[] = $row['title'];
        $summaryTopic[] = $row['summary'];
        $randomStringTopic[] = $row['randomString'];

    }

}
```

**Insert single SELECT statement**

And I know it is possible to do all that in a single SELECT statement - but I've been out of the 'game' for a little while and I can't seem to get it to work

What should work is something along the lines of the suggested solution

```
SELECT <select_list> FROM forumtopic t LEFT JOIN forumtopicview v ON t.userID = v.userID AND t.id = v.topicID WHERE t.userID <> ? AND v.id IS NULL
```

And it excludes all topics written by user logged in (t.userID <> ?)
But doesn't exclude the ones viewed by user logged in already (t.userID = v.userID AND t.id = v.topicID)

Hope someone can help

Comment: btw: there is an error in your sql (there are 2 where clauses)

Comment: If you still want an answer, don't accept the question. Or if it causes you to change your question, post a new question. Also please don't add 'EDIT's, *edit* your question to make it the best possible phrasing of whatever you are asking. Please also read & act on [mcve]. Please also format your code so the SQL is also formatted.

Comment: `left join` returns rows that `inner join` does plus unmatched left table rows extended by `null`s. `on` binds more tightly than `where` but is otherwise the same.

Comment: You are not clear. Eg you say a suggested answer "worked" but it didn't work. Eg: There is little point in telling us what algebraic operations your query does; we know what it does, we need to know what rows you think are in the tables along the way. So after some editing by me your specification "[forumtopic rows for] topics [not] written by the[ir] user and [not] viewed by the[ir] user" is helpful. Same for 1 "[forumtopic rows for] topics not written by the[ir] user". But 2 & 3 are not clear. Tell us what rows you want/expect in terms of what rows are in base relations or rows so far.

Comment: PS You don't tell what rows in your base tables say. No one can use the datbase unless you do. What does a row in forumtopic says about its id, userID, etc. Right now it's not clear what you mean by "topics not written by the user".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All topics not written by the user and not viewed by the user

```
SELECT
      t.id
    , t.date
    , t.dateEdit
    , t.userID
    , t.title
    , t.summary
    , t.randomString
FROM forumtopic t
LEFT JOIN forumtopicview v ON t.userID = v.userID AND t.id = v.topicID
WHERE t.userID <> ? 
AND v.id IS NULL
```

Note: When joining tables it becomes very important to include table names or table aliases in ALL column references. This avoids errors caused by common column names causing ambiguity.

### EDIT

```
SELECT
      t.id
    , t.date
    , t.dateEdit
    , t.userID
    , t.title
    , t.summary
    , t.randomString
FROM forumtopic t
WHERE t.userID <> ? 
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM forumtopicview v where t.id = v.topicID
        AND v.userID = ?
        )
```

Comment: You are both right on the notation and off course there shouldn't be 2 WHERE clauses - the first WHERE clause should be appended to the second
And it worked - so thank you

Comment: There is only one `WHERE` clause. The other is an `ON` clause. There are subtle differences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722795/in-sql-mysql-what-is-the-difference-between-on-and-where-in-a-join-statem

Comment: @Randall Left join returns rows that inner join does plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. `on` binds more tightly than `where` but is otherwise the same. This is not "subtle". In a poor descripiton these differences might be *obscured*, but that's a property of poor descriptions, not of left vs right join or on vs where.

Comment: @Randall 2 where clauses exist in the query within the question. APM was referring to a comment I made under the question.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I'm sorry I first accepted and then took back acceptance - it was 2 AM and I went from getting no results to your solution getting results - and the code looked like it would do what I wanted - so I jumped the gun - sorry about that - your solution seems to take all topics not written by user (correct) but doesn't remove any already viewed - sorry for the confusion - I really appreciate your effort - would you have any idea how to change your code so it'll do what I'm trying to do? - it's probably something really small but I can't seem to find it - again thank you for help

Comment: can you please try the second query above?

Comment: @Used_By_Already absolute perfection... you sir are a genius :D - thank you - and this time it is tested and not just 'hmmm looks like it works' - that does exactly what I was after... clearly I need to brush up on my Boolean logic in MySQL queries (I seem to have forgotten more than I care to remember) and I will def do that now (your approach didn't even occur to me) - so again thank you and your accepted answer mark is back where it belongs