# Update a Field Using Last Rows Fields value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, updates

Suppose I have the following table:

| CustomerId | Amount | Date | LastMonthDate | SumLastMonthAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 20220301 | 20220201 | 500 |
| 1 | 200 | 20220304 | 20220204 | 700 |
| 1 | 400 | 20220320 | 20220220 | 1100 |
| 1 | 100 | 20220329 | 20220229 | 1200 |
| 1 | 100 | 20220402 | 20220302 | 800 |

As you can see, I want to have sum of amount for last month; suppose that `SumLastMonth` is `NULL` in the table, how should I update this column?

Note that you can't use date functions at all. and our date columns have int type as you see

The query that I wrote for this task is:

```
UPDATE A
SET SumLastMonthAmount = (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                          FROM Table B 
                          WHERE A.CustomerId = B.CustomerId
                            AND B.Date > A.LastMonthDate
                            AND B.Date <= A.Date)                          
FROM Table A
Where A.Date=20220402
```

But it is very slow. Can you suggest a better query?

Comment: Please add number of records in your table and logic behind the updates..

Comment: Performance issues are often best approached by examining the _actual execution plan_. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: The query is slow, in part, because it is doing an `UPDATE` to every row in the table. If your older data are not changing frequently, you should consider adding a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` to limit the set of rows it operates over

Comment: @Nitika number of records for each day is about 1 million . we want to use amount of last month for each customer in our calculation

Comment: @paneerakbari Yes You are right. i added where clause for date and update  for each date individuali but it is timespending.

Comment: Does table `B` have an index on 'CustomerId' and `Date` that includes `Amount`, i.e. a [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/)?

Comment: @nasim_bbb please update your question with the new `WHERE` clause you have added.

Comment: @HABO yes it have

Answer (score 0):

your code is modified as below. if last month is not identified "last Month amount" will be null

```sql
with cte as(
    select  A.CustomerId , A.LastMonthDate, A.Date,SUM(B.Amount) as newLastMonthAmount 
    from Table A 
    left Join Table B  
    on A.CustomerId = B.CustomerId 
    AND B.Date > A.LastMonthDate 
    AND B.Date <= A.Date 
    group by A.CustomerId , A.LastMonthDate, A.Date
) 
update A 
set SumLastMonthAmount=B.newLastMonthAmount 
from Table A 
join cte B 
on  A.CustomerId = B.CustomerId 
AND B.Date = A.Date 
AND B.LastMonthDate = A.LastMonthDate
```

Comment: Use `join on where` instead of `join on and`. For more refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722834/16019058)

Comment: Used left join bcz he need not matched records to be null so if use where condition that can't be possible

Comment: `AND B.Date > A.LastMonthDate AND B.Date <= A.Date` should be `where B.Date > A.LastMonthDate AND B.Date <= A.Date`